# Scale values in uniform way?

Tags: python, numpy, scale, uniform

I have an array of numbers that I convert to percentages ( values in the range [0 .. 1]). Which then I convert to gray colors.

Example :

```
 percentage = nums/float(nums.max())
```

the problem is most of the values are small numbers with couple of big numbers. This causes most of the % to be around 0.01.
The result is that this translates to ~~white color which becomes invisible when plotting.
BTW I have to keep all the values.

I tried to scale down the outliers abit , but even this does not help ;(

```
 colors[abs(colors - np.mean(colors)) > 2 * np.std(colors)] = colors.mean() + 2 * np.std(colors)
 c = colors/float(colors.max()) #convert to percentage
```

what this does is to scale down the outliers to 2std off the mean.

What I think I need is some sort of "step-wise" function which groups the values in such a way that they are scaled evenly 
in the range 0 .. 1 so that every point receives visible color, but still keeps some contrast so that the values are distinguished.

PS> May be the range has to be from 0.1 to 1 !

=====

this so far this is some sort of solution :

```
 c += 0.15 * (1-c)
```

Comment: Maybe you should read about [Histogram Equalization](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/color_exposure/plot_equalize.html)

Comment: If it's working, can you please accept the answer and close this question? If you found another solution, that fit your needs better, it is also appreciated, if you would share it here in a separate answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this so far this is the best solution :

c += 0.15 * (1-c)

Answer (score 1):

Thinking of usual photo-editing, would it be a solution to cut off some values? Then, a usual sorting could help, like

```
highlights=np.sort(nums)[-xyz:]
```

and just set these values to the next smaller value to set this white.

Of course this can be a severe manipulation of data, but this is, what you're doing usually in GIMP or similar photo manipulation software, when you're adjusting color curves. So if these outliers are just like erratic pixels and you are actually interested in the grayscaled values in the middle, this might be helpful.

I hope, I got your interest right,
lepakk